# Unclear structure variable usage - C

Tags: c, linux, data-structures, linux-kernel

While browsing through the Linux kernel code, I came across something like this.

```
struct dma_chan {
        int  lock;
        const char *device_id;
};

static struct dma_chan dma_chan_busy[MAX_DMA_CHANNELS] = {
        [4] = { 1, "cascade" },
};
```

what is this - `[4] = { 1, "cascade" },` - usage implying ?

Note : Kernel version is 2.6.32

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [designated initializer.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) It initializes the fifth element to `{ 1, "cascade" }` explicitly, the other ones are default-initialized.